# Why "Chan chan" has the A chord?

Tags: chords, scales, chord-progressions

How come "Chan Chan" by "Buena Vista Social Club" uses the A chord, since it's in D minor? Shouldn't the chord progression be Dm Edim F Gm A Bb C?

Or, put another way, is there a key that has the chords the song uses, i.e. Dm F Gm A?

Comment: The A chord is perfectly fine in D minor. It's the dominant and it's used all the time. Please take a look at [this question](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/16248/9724) and its answers for a better understanding of minor key harmony.

Comment: And even if it didn't have a diatonic excuse to be in a D minor tune, remember that chromatic chords and notes - ones that aren't in the main scale of a key - are frequently used.  And you can't keep calling "modulation" or "borrowed chord" every time a chromatic harmony appears.  (Well, you can, but it's a bit silly.)

Comment: I don't think this question is an exact duplicate of https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16248/understanding-minor-key-harmony but just a concrete application. It would be very useful to answer this as "they are using the harmonic minor scale", check this other link for a detailed explanation.