# Barre chord indication above the measure

Tags: notation, fingering

What does the indication BVII6 mean. I know it's a barre chord position but I  don't understand what the number means.

It has been suggested that I include an image so I will try:
[image: the image is of measures 9 through 13 with the areas in question circled. you can see the indicated BIV3 and BVII6 are circled in red. what do the numbers after the roman numerals mean? This is a classical piece.]

Comment: Never come across that. Any chance of an image?

Comment: Seems to be answered here: [https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/what-does-the-roman-numeral-notation-mean-for-this-borrowed-chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/what-does-the-roman-numeral-notation-mean-for-this-borrowed-chord)

Comment: Just to be clear on things, does it show a B or a b, where b could be a flat?  Flat 6 would indicate that the root of the chord is b6, which would be Ab in C, and the 6 could either mean first inversion if it's classical notation, which should have the 6 in superscript, or it could be a major 6 chord.  If it is indeed a notation for a barre chord, I wouldn't be familiar with that notation.  As Tim suggested, an image would be very helpful in determining what is actually being called for with this symbol.

Comment: @LaurencePayne Nice catch! Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would guess it is a B chord on the 7th fret (VII) with the root on the 6th string (low E).

Comment: b3ko, Tim, please look at the image I added to my original question, because I'm not sure that your answer is the one I need.